# Jquery function only works on page load, fails to run after AJAx load of data

Tags: jquery, html-table

We have the following script, when the page is first loaded we call `FindPromo()` this function in particular waits for the children of the `HTML Table` to load.

It then finds all `td's` with the class `.promotion` and at the same time checks to make sure that `td` is currently in the users view by calling `checkvisible` if it is then we assign the additional `promoSelect` to it, we also call this when the user scrolls through the table, if they scroll and a `td` with the class `promotion` comes into view we again assign `promoSelect` to it.

We then call `GetPromo` this the loops the `table` finds the `td's` that have the class `promoSelect` and retrieve's a value from it - So far this is working perfectly fine.

The issue:

At the top of table, there are 4 `buttons`, the 4 `buttons` allow the `user` to load different data which is done via `AJAX`, which in turn populates the `html` table again, when the `user` presses one of the `buttons` I wired up a click event to call `FindPromo()` again, however it doesn't seem to append the `promoSelect` class to any `td's` that have the class `.promotion` after the data has been loaded successfully, even though I have checked the `td's` and I can see several that have the class `.promotion`.

Now I've placed `console.logs` inside `FindPromo()` / `GetPromo()` and they appear to write to the console, yet the script fails to run after the `user` has pushed one of the 4 buttons.

Script:

```
// Called on page load and when the user clicks on 1 of the four buttons
function FindPromo() {

var checkExist = setInterval(function () {

var length = $('table.tst-orderProductsTable').find('tbody').children().length;

if (length > 0) {

  clearInterval(checkExist);

  $('tbody').scroll(function () { 
    $('.promotion').filter(checkVisible).addClass('promoSelect'); // Find all promotion td's and assign promoSelect class to them
    GetPromo();
  }).scroll();

}
}, 500);
}

function checkVisible() {
  var elm = this;
  var eval = eval || "visible";
  var vpH = $(window).height(), // Viewport Height
  st = $(window).scrollTop(), // Scroll Top
  y = $(elm).offset().top,
  elementHeight = $(elm).height();

  if (eval == "visible") return ((y < (vpH + st)) && (y > (st - elementHeight)));
}


// Now loop the td's and find all td's that have the class promoSelect.
// Then retrieve information from that td
function GetPromo() { 

var product_description = '';
var product_position = '';

$("td").each(function (i, row) {

    if ($(this).hasClass('promoSelect')) {
      console.log("here");
    }

 });
}


// clicking 1 of the four buttons above table.
$('.product-tab-label').click(function () {

  FindPromo();

});

FindPromo();
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "fails to run"?  Is there an error on the console?  When you debug, what happens when the function is invoked?  How specifically does it fail?

Comment: @David when I say fails to run, it doesn't find all td's with the class promotion after the user has pressed one of the four buttons.  However on page load it works perfectly fine.

Comment: So specifically in the callback to `.scroll()` the selector `$('.promotion')` returns no matching elements?  That would strongly suggest that no such elements exist on the page at that time.  Are they being dynamically modified or unloaded/reloaded from the DOM in some way?

Comment: I've checked the HTML after the table has been reloaded after pressing one of the buttons, and I can see several td's with the class promotion.  I believe they are being reloaded after 1 of the four buttons are pressed

Comment: You may need to do some more careful debugging then.  Because if there's some asynchronous operation which unloads and reloads them and you're trying to select them while that operation is being performed then they won't be available at that time.  If your debugging has indeed revealed that the given selector finds no elements, then there are no matching elements.

Answer (score 0):

When attaching events to an element, you can use a direct approach or a delegated approach. Here's what the direct looks like:

```
 $('.product-tab-label').click(function () {

  FindPromo();

});
```

Here, each .product-tab-label has been individually given instructions. If new .product-tab-label's get created [which is what happens when the DOM changes], these new elements don't have any instruction and won't respond to clicks [and subsequently, FindPromo(); will 'fail to run']. 
Each .product-tab-label is **directly** responsible for its own events.

Since you want the instructions to survive across DOM changes, you'll need to use delegated events.

```
$( ".product-tab-label-parent" ).on( "click", ,".product-tab-label" ,function() {
   FindPromo();
});
```

In this case, the instructions are given to a parent element(.product-tab-label-parent) and it attaches the events to its children even when they change.

There's a section on direct and delegated events here: https://api.jquery.com/on/

Going by the code you've shown, I'll guess that table.tst-orderProductsTable is a suitable parent element. Use this:

```
$( "table.tst-orderProductsTable" ).on( "click", ,".product-tab-label" ,function() {
   FindPromo();
});
```